# web crawl with submit or input

Tags: web-crawler

it must be a stupid question, but I am just wondering if one can crawl website that requires some input (or submit a form) first?

Take google for example, if I have a list of search item. I want the program to be able to "type in" the 1st keyword in the list first (ie java), then crawl the result page. Then "type in" python and crawl the result page.

```
["java", "python" ...]
```

Comment: "take google for example"... the moment they detect robot-like behaviour, you have to answer a captcha and your programming will stop working.